How to extend Express Request type with custom fields
I'm working on a Node.js project using TypeScript and Express, and I want to add a custom field (marketplaceId) to the Express Request object via middleware. Here’s my current setup across three packages:

Package: Interface Declaration
In this package, I declare the interface that extends the Express Request object:
import { Request } from 'express';

export interface RequestWithMarketplaceId extends Request {
  marketplaceId: string;
}


Package: Middleware Implementation
In the second package, I implement the middleware that will utilize the extended request interface:
import { RequestWithMarketplaceId } from '@api-utils';
import { Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

// Middleware to ensure only one marketplace ID is provided
const ensureSingleMarketplace = (req: RequestWithMarketplaceId, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  ...
};

export default ensureSingleMarketplace;


Service Integration
In my service, I apply the middleware to ensure that the marketplaceId is included when handling incoming requests:
import { ensureSingleMarketplace } from 'middlewares';
import { RequestWithMarketplaceId } from 'api-utils';

private intialiseRoutes(): void {
  ...
  this.router.post(`${this.path}/`, ensureSingleMarketplace, this.method);
}

private method = async (req: RequestWithMarketplaceId, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
...
}



Then I got this error:
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: RequestWithMarketplaceId, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: RequestWithMarketplaceId, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
        Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
          Property 'marketplaceId' is missing in type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' but required in type 'RequestWithMarketplaceId'.ts(2769)

I attempted to create a express.d.ts file to globally extend the Request type, but I'm unsure if it's the right approach or if I implemented it correctly.

Here you are a detailed example about how to do it: https://blog.logrocket.com/extend-express-request-object-typescript/
